# HorizontalScrollView does not fill parent view

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I want to scroll my text view text in vertically and horizontally, it works but horizontal scroll bar appear exactly bottom of last line, instead i want this on bottom of scroll-view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D7D1CA"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.hortiplus.PracticeExamActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="This is layout  This is sample text This is sample text "
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
  </ScrollView>
  <-- Some other Linear Layout goes here   -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="This is layout  Thefwef fwf jkne fwnfiw wofjwoifj is is sample text This is sample text "
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I swapped around ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

`fill_parent` is depreciated. Please use `match_parent` instead and see if that fixes your issue.